# Read the text file ,split the line in a text file and send the email for that line using nant scripting

Tags: nant

I have a below requirement to be done using nant scripting
1) Read the text file line by line and split the line 
2) Each line should be sent as an email to the concerned team

Answer (score 3):

Using the [`<foreach />`](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/foreach.html) and [`<mail />`](http://nant.sourceforge.net/release/latest/help/tasks/mail.html) tasks. Here's a quick snippet from the excellent NAnt documentation:

```
<foreach item="Line" in="yourfile.txt" delim="," property="x,y">
    <mail message="Read pair ${x}=${y}" />
</foreach>
```

Comment: I did it in the similar way, but email is not getting triggered to the To list present in the <mail/> tag

Comment: @sandy - update your question with that part of your script, perhaps we can spot the problem.